# Get the first value of a json

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a json like this in an Athena table:

```
 input 
 [14587979, {ke1:4,ke2:4}]
```

I would like to get the fist value "14587979"

but when I use  json_extract like this:

`json_extract(input, "$[0]") as id`

I get the below  error

Query execution failed

> Reason:
> SQL Error [100071] [HY000]: [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:22: Column '$[0]' cannot be resolved

how Can I get the first  value?

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes, double quotes are used to escape column/table/schema names (if for some example the name contains restricted character like space):

```sql
select json_extract('[14587979, {ke1:4,ke2:4}]', '$[0]');
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 14587979 |